# Finding all questions I have asked that are "un-answered"?

Tags: support

I have been asking more than a few questions here. I have never – that I know of – marked any of them as "answered". How can I bring up a screen of questions I have asked so I can mark them – individually – as answered as appropriate?

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/users/73534/greenber?tab=questions&sort=activity) lists all your questions and indicates if they have answers or not.

Comment: You have 10 accepted answers, by the way. Not sure how you could be unaware of that. Wouldn't doing the same thing 10 times give you at least a vague memory of having done it before?

Comment: I don't hang out on SuperUser and have never read the manual/instructions:  as the kids so annoyingly say -- "my bad". I come in, ask my question and leave.  Wait: it looks like Sathya has answered me,c, completely ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst this is overkill since you currently only have 38 questions some of which are closed, it is possible to query StackExchange sites for this kind of information using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com).

The following query will show questions with answers but none that are marked as 'accepted':

```sql
select q.Title, 'http://superuser.com/questions/' + cast(q.ID as varchar) as [Link]
from Posts q
where q.PostTypeId = 1 and q.OwnerUserId = 73534 and q.AcceptedAnswerId is null and ClosedDate is null and AnswerCount > 0
order by CreationDate desc
```

Query results can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/revision/339428/438023/greenber-unanswered-questions).

Note that it seems to take a little while for the results to be synchronised with the live data.

Comment: Check my answer for an easier approach

Comment: +1 for the approach, most simple and straightforward way to do it. I didn't know superuser has db until I read this answer, this is much more powerful than only searching answer which is un-answered, it can slot any status of the question/user/answer.

Answer (score 5):

An easier solution is to make use of `user:me hasaccepted:no` search operator. This will give you [all questions that](https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A73534%20hasaccepted%3Ano) you have not accepted.

Check the [Search page](https://superuser.com/search) and click on "Advanced Search Tips" for more such tips